# how to echo a hierarchical data into a file in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell variable called :

```
check=$(grep text mytext.txt)
#grep text mytext.txt will give an output like: 
#text.1
#text.2
#text.3
```

How do I echo the below content into a file as-is :

```
data:  
   updatevalues: |-
      #${check}
      text.1
      text.2
      text.3
```

Tried doing this way :

```
 printf "data:\n   updatevalues: | \n    `echo "$check"` " >> myfile.txt
```

But I am not able to align $check :

```
data:  
   updatevalues: |-
      #${check}
      text.1
text.2
text.3
```

Comment: `echo "$var"` here is a useless use of echo. It's like `echo $(echo $(echo "$var")))`. Just use `$var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepend spaces to each line of a stream easily with `sed`.

```
{
     echo    "data:"
     echo    "   updatevalues: |-"
     echo    '      #${check}'
     sed 's/^/      /'  <<<"$check"
} > myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option of piping `grep` directly to a command, rather than capturing its output, I would do that.

```
grep text mytext.txt | {
  printf 'data:\n'
  printf '   updatevalues: |-\n'
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '      %s\n' "$line"
  done
}
```

(The first two `printf` calls could come before the pipe, rather than in the loop.

```
printf 'data:\n'
printf '   updatevalues: |-\n'
grep text mytext.txt | {
  ...
}
```

)

Though you can still print the value of `check` through the pipe as well:

```
echo "$check
" | {
  ...
}
```

The additional newline is added because the command substitution would have stripped it, and `read` relies on it to work properly.

Comment: Thank you so much :) this work too :) But unfortunately, that grep was just an example and my actual output of the variable "check" Is quite big so I would not like to grep it over since that is used in many places in my code already

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
check=$(grep text mytext.txt | sed 's/^/      /')
```

or

```
check=$(sed '/text/{s/^/      /}' mytext.txt)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works for me too :) But I do not have code flexibility to change the "check" variable because It is more complex than a grep command here.